# SDL2/SDL.H file not found

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm following this tutorial on youtube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44tO977slsU

and he links a video on how to install SDL2, I follow that video, and I followed this one as well. But when I compile it keeps coming up with SDL2/SDL not found? I'm not sure how to fix this

Here is my code so far
**MAIN.CPP**

```cpp
#include "Game.hpp"

Game *game =nullptr;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    game = new Game();

    game->init("Nijigen-Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, false);

    while (game->running()) {

        game->handleEvents();
        game->update();
        game->render();
    }

    game->clean();

    return 0;
}
```

**Game.cpp**

```cpp
#include "Game.hpp"

Game::Game()
{}
Game::~Game()
{}

void Game::init(const char *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen)
{

    int flags = 0;
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        flags = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Subsystems Initiated!..." << std::endl;

        window = SDL_CreateWindow(title, xpos, ypos, width, height, flags);
        if(window)
        {
            std::cout << "Window Created!..." << std::endl;
        }

        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
        if(renderer)
        {
            SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
            std::cout << "Renderer Created!..." << std::endl;
        }

        isRunning = true;
    } else {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}

void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            isRunning = false;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}

void Game::update()
{}

void Game::render()
{
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
}

void Game::clean()
{
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
    std::cout << "Game Cleaned" << std::endl;

}
```

** And Game.hpp**

```cpp
#ifndef Game_hpp
#define Game_hpp
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

class Game {

public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool running() { return isRunning; }


private:
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};

#endif /* Game_hpp */
```

Comment: It means that the folder containing the `SDL2` folder is not in your compiler's include paths.

Comment: `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"`  you may want to change this to `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>` since I assume the `SDL2` folder is not in your project.

Comment: I did that, but it still came up with SDL2/SDL.h file not found

Comment: Here is my current header search path /Users/106266/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework